# Bounding the error in Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion, definition

Consider Taylor polynomial

$$P_{n,a}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$$

Approximating $f(x)$ in a neighborhood of $a$. Then we have remainder function with the relationship $P_{n,a}(x) + R_{n,a}(x) = f(x)$ or $R_{n,a}(x) = f(x) - P_{n,a}(x)$.

Take $n+1$ derivatives of both sides as we get $R^{(n+1)}_{n,a}(x) = f^{(n+1)}(x)$.

At this point we're supposed to bound the derivative so when we integrate back up we back error bounds for $R_{n,a}(x)$. But does it even make sense to write

$$|f^{(n+1)}(x) | < M$$

I am a little stuck because apparently we can only bound the error between $x$ (the point we care about) and $a$ (some nearby value for which we can easily compute $f^{(k)}(a)$ values). But we already have an $x$ in the term?

I mean I don't think I can say $|f^{(n+1)}(x) | < M$ $\forall x \in (a, x)$ because that doesn't make sense. Or am I supposed to write $|f^{(n+1)}(t) | < M$ $\forall t \in (a, x)$? Like what's the usual way people write this so that when they do the $n+1$ integrations they end up at something that looks like $|R_{n,a}(x)| < \frac{M (x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ or whatever it's supposed to be? What's the correct range of integration? $a$ to $x$? What about when $a > x$, so $x$ to $a$? Do we have to prove both cases? Or do you do generic bounds?

I wish there were clearer information about this online in its derivation. Most websites skip all this stuff and jump right to the end result with very little explanation in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $R_{n,a}^{(n+1)}(x)=f^{(n+1)}(x)$. We even know $R_{n,a}^{(k)}(a)=0$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$. Thus we actually have a well-defined ODE IVP for $R_{n,a}$, if we are given a function $f$ which is $(n+1)$ times continuously differentiable. Nonetheless this is not generally possible to solve explicitly, so it is not really useful by itself.

On the other hand, one can use this as an alternative derivation of a Lagrange-type error estimate, since it implies that the error is exactly given by:

$$R_{n,a}(x)=\int_a^x \int_a^{t_1} \dots \int_a^{t_n} f^{(n+1)}(t_{n+1}) dt_{n+1} dt_n dt_{n-1} \dots dt_1.$$

Taking absolute values and applying the triangle inequality results in the usual Lagrange-type error estimate $|R_{n,a}(x)| \leq M \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ where $M$ is a bound on $|f^{(n+1)}(t)|$ for $t \in (a,x)$.

The actual Lagrange error formula says something a bit better than this estimate, namely that the error is *exactly* given by $f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x)) \frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ for some $\xi(x) \in (a,x)$. But since $\xi(x)$ generally cannot be computed, most of the time the Lagrange error formula is used to obtain the Lagrange type error estimate.

Comment: Is $M$ then equal to $\max(f^{(n+1)}(t)) \forall t \in(a,x)$ (I don't know the right way to write "max value of this function over this interval). Furthermore where are all these $t$ terms coming from in ths integral?

Comment: @user525966 $M$ is any bound on $\max_{t \in [a,x]} |f^{(n+1)}(t)|$; it doesn't have to be the exact maximum. The integral is just how you would solve the ODE $g^{(n+1)}(x)=f^{(n+1)}(x),g(a)=0,g'(a)=0,\dots,g^{(n)}(a)=0$. The use of the $t$ variables does not matter, I just chose symbols for the integration variables that aren't already being used outside the scope of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

The real statement of *Taylor-Lagrange theorem* is that 
$$R_{n,a}(x)=f^{(n+1)}(\xi)\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\quad\text{for some $\;\xi$ between $a$ and $x$}, $$so $M$ is just an upper bound for all these possible $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$ in a neighbourhood of $a$. In $\;f^{(n+1)}(x) <M$, the $x$ is just a dummy variable.

Comment: I don't know what that means or where it comes from -- right now I'm still on the step where we take $n+1$ derivatives of everything. I'm trying to learn this concept from the ground up instead of accepting things without proof

Comment: Do you know the *Mean value theorem*?

Comment: I do not, unfortunately

Comment: Taylor's theorem is an extension of this result (it assert that for a differentiable function $f$, $f(x)=f(a)+f'(\xi)(x-a)$ for some $\xi$) to the case of $n+1$ times differentiable functions. It is one of the fundamental theorems in *Analysis*.

Comment: Is it easier to start with the < M version first? I am just trying to figure out at the moment what the relevant boundary conditions are that we are discussing

Comment: It's easier to use, but conceptually, the other comes first.

Comment: Looking on Wiki but already confused. $f$ is continuous on closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on open interval $(a, b)$? I thought continuity at $a$ meant $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ by definition, so if we know $f(a)$ can be evaluated, doesn't that also mean it's differentiable, i.e. $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ exists? Or stated another way $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$?

Comment: But $a$ in your problem is not a bound of the interval. The theorem says $f$ has to be continuous on a closed bounded interval, and differentiable inside this interval. At the bounds, it may or may not be differentiable, that is unimportant.

Comment: So MVT basically says there is a point inside the interval whose tangent slope is the same as the slope connecting $a$ and $b$, right?

Comment: Yes, but it can be rewritten in Taylor's form, as I said.

Comment: I think I need to learn how MVT works first before understanding this answer